# How do I sort values in a list of arrays based on two separate elements in the array?

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I have a list as follows:

```
my_list = [['Sample',
  'B1',
  17,
  (0.10996957123279572,
   0.012014645151793957,
   0.07346764951944351,
   0.7748424410820007)],
 ['Errand',
  'F8',
  55,
  (0.8701117634773254,
   0.029884250834584236,
   0.0895276814699173,
   0.3274153172969818)],
 ['Date',
  'X5',
  90.69985961914062,
  (0.07959063351154327,
   0.011931813322007656,
   0.10205486416816711,
   0.908562958240509)],
 ['State',
  'C3',
  92,
  (0.15565741062164307,
   0.010158938355743885,
   0.1308525949716568,
   0.6345445513725281)],
 ['Name',
  'G4',
  89,
  (0.1520645171403885,
   0.010264626704156399,
   0.15941078960895538,
   0.4947034418582916)],...]
```

The list inside of the element `(a,b,c,d)` is what I need to use to sort the list.
This list is of the form `(width, height, left, top)` and corresponds to the location of a bounding box rectangle where the word (first element, like 'Sample', 'Errand', etc) was found.

I need to sort this list based on the order that they appear on the image. This order is from Top to Bottom, Left to Right.

The way that I have tried to sort this list is as follows:

```
s1 = sorted(my_list, key = lambda x: x[3][2], reverse=False)
s2 = sorted(s1, key = lambda x: x[3][3], reverse=False)
```

This correctly sorts them from top to bottom, but does not order them from left to right (it orders them from right to left).

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: If it's ordering them RtL, but you want LtR, wouldn't setting `reverse=True` do the trick?

Comment: You [got that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75306725/12671057) with `reverse=True`. You changed it to `reverse=False`. Why did you do that when it's not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a two-element tuple as your sort key. That will often be more efficient than doing two sorts - although a bit more memory-intensive than doing a single `sorted` call and then an in-place `sort`.

Tuples sort by their first element, then the second if needed to break ties in the first element and so forth. So if you want top to bottom as the highest priority and then ties in height broken left to right, a two-element tuple will do that.

In some cases, an in-place second sort may be faster than a tuple key. A commenter and I are showing different results for that comparison. It may be worthwhile to profile in your environment - and with a list length that accurately represents your expected data. I get different performance breakpoints depending on the length of the list.

You can negate the numeric value to invert the sort order interpretation of one element. From looking at your first version, I'm not sure where your origin is but if it's bottom left you'd want to negate the `top` field but not `left`:

`s = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (-x[3][3], x[3][2]))`

Comment: The origin is on the top left!

Comment: Hmm, with top left I'd expect default-order sorting to do the right thing for you - it's lowest to highest, so as long as your tuples are (top, left) that'll start with the top left and work towards bottom right. Your first stab at it looks like it ought to work because of the stability of Python sorts - are you sure you're actually getting ties in the `top` field that would make the left-to-right sort kick in? A small difference in `top` will override any difference in `left`.

Comment: What do you mean with "more efficient"? It seems [slower](https://tio.run/##fVFNb8MgDL3zK3wEifawXKZI@Re7RRFKFbOhFYgM7Zpfn0JIsnaaaiFhP56fPxin@OVd9T7SPGvyFqKxCMaOnuLiswWl3g3pWvESMWYndTYhQgNtGyJxIyRst5HAC4@n6JUnOga/pj2BAePy8yfyarFEYQNq8A75WlTUSxZhvJCDkNrCYXuT8I1Tc@7taejhVgM/3NqqS0fC4rx1QhTB@OP/CIY0zWu1TaLQj5nM/2HkaoRXpIDNB11QPPXL2EjGRf44ETTNU0OC5WWoh2WsPWZYZzhly5xS7xvMn5G/jYsd0rvgDpXa@qiU6y0qJdccOKykQhDzfAc) and does take more memory.

Comment: @KellyBundy - your version uses an in-place sort for the second sort, which is a valid optimization - I'll update to mention that. A tuple key is more efficient than chaining `sorted()` calls - on my PC I get 437s for `timeit.timeit('sorted(sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[3][2]), key=lambda x: x[3][3], reverse=True)', number=1000, globals=globals())` vs 347s for `timeit.timeit('sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (-x[3][3], x[3][2]))', number=1000, globals=globals())`.

Comment: @KellyBundy - Actually, I get 433s for `timeit.timeit('sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: x[3][2]).sort(key=lambda x: x[3][3], reverse=True)', number=1000, globals=globals())` - meaning it edges out the chained `sorted()` calls, barely, but still loses to the tuple key. Do you see anything invalid with that `timeit` test? I generally find that more reliable than just the wall-clock style test you linked to.

Comment: Further testing shows that on my PC the length of the list is - unsurprisingly - a factor, the in-place sort is winning at 333 but losing at 333333 for me.

Comment: Your tests look alright. I'd put something like that into the answer. It's the **"will** be more efficient" claim without any evidence that bothers me. Especially since I've had two simpler sorts win against one more complicated sort many times (maybe more often than not), so I know that it depends, and either could be faster. And the single sort with tuples definitely takes a lot more memory. I made the second sort inplace not really for the little speed improvement but rather because it takes less memory and creating another list is just pointless and I don't like to advocate it.

Comment: I use timeit for microbenchmarks, but when something takes a second already, I prefer simple time mostly because it's shorter to type (especially on my phone) and read. And sometimes because it doesn't disable garbage collection, when I don't want that. (In timeit I can re-enable it, but that's again more code).